# How do I display external JSON using Pug/Jade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handlebars.js, pug

I am trying to figure out how to use pug to iterate through a JSON object retrieved via a GET request from an API. Can anyone point me to a resource or provide an example of making a GET request and then iterating through an object within a Pug template? I have been looking for documentation on this to no avail.

I know how to do this in handlebars but is it possible in PUG/Jade?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you doing it in the browser?

Comment: This is all client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, in index.js:

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        var json =[{id:1,name:foo,},{id:2, name:foooo}]
        res.render('index',{title: 'title', json});
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Then in your index.pug, you can iterate over the object json like this:

```
each elem,i in json
    p !{elem.id}-!{elem.name}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what `router` is referencing in this case? Is that native javascript?

Comment: the first part, is tipically how you made a get request in node-express app. The second part, is how you can iterate over the object passed.

In this case res.render('index', {title:'title', json}, title and json are two vars passed to the pug file index.